# uploaded % and current speed in "simple FTP sample"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ftp, data-transfer

In the [SimpleFTPSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html) by Apple, is it possible to display the transfer speed and the % uploaded of the current file?

Comment: So you want to know how to retrieve progress information when using `CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL`?

Comment: yes and also the upload speed. thanks for any help.

Comment: Well, once having the progress information the upload speed is just a trivial calculation away assuming you've noted the time the upload started, current time and current progress..?

Comment: but thatwould give me the average speed, not the current speed..

Comment: if you need a more precise display just store the delta value and time between two last progress update calls